# Printing a meaningful message on test failure using jUnit, Selenium Webdriver and continuing the script

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jenkins, hamcrest

Forgive the beginner question.  I have a Webdriver script (Java, JUnit4) which tests a number of very similar webpages for common elements.

Some of the webpages have dates on them, some do not.  For those that do not, I want to the test result to print "The current date is not displayed" and then continue to run the remainder of the @Test's.

Code snippet I am using:

```
@Test
public void checkIfTodaysDateDisplayed(){

    WebElement currentDate = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".currentDate"));
    assertEquals("The current date is not displayed", currentDate.isDisplayed());

}
```

Currently, on those pages that don't contain the date, a NoSuchElementException is thrown and Jenkins test result simply shows: "Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".currentDate"}"

What I want to achieve is: 
a) print a meaningful message
b) do not halt the test as there are 5 or 6 other @Test's I need to run for each page.

What is the best/optimal solution to fix the assertion and handle this?  A Try/Catch block?

EDIT: updated code:

```
WebElement currentDate = null;
    try {
        currentDate = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".currentDate"));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        Assert.fail("The current date is not displayed! " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Assert.assertNotNull(currentDate);
    Assert.assertEquals("The current date is displayed", currentDate.isDisplayed());
```

If page DOES have a date, the console prints:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :The current date is displayed
Actual   :true
```

If page DOESN'T have a date, the console prints:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"css  selector","selector":".currentDate"}
```

Answer (score 1):

**To A)**

Yes, one solution is to wrap your first line into a try-catch block. Be sure to catch **only** the Exception you expect and no other as your test will contain holes then.

Your code might look like this:

```
@Test
public void checkIfTodaysDateDisplayed(){

    WebElement currentDate = null;
    try {
        currentDate = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".currentDate"));
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        Assert.fail("Web page is not properly set up! " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Assert.assertNotNull(currentDate);
    Assert.assertEquals("The current date is not displayed", currentDate.isDisplayed());
}
```

You may want to append additional information to your Asserts, such as the exception stacktrace or whatever is needed for you to debug.

**To B)**

Write singular tests for each case you want to have tested. If you put everything in one monolithic test it'll be more difficult to chase the exact position where your test failed. Write tests that do **not** depend on each other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have tried suggested try/catch block but still get the NoSuchElementException without the "Web page is not set up" message.  Not sure why.  I agree in respect of b) - singular tests is the way to go

Comment: Try to find the exact line that produces your NoSuchElementException. Is your try-catch block set up correctly? If so, use the debugger to step through the code until it throws the exception.

Comment: thanks. I've set the try/catch as per your suggestion and exception isthrown at line currentDate = driver.find..........

Comment: Ok, nice. If it helped, feel free to mark my post as solution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the exception is still thrown and not handled, and I don't get the nice, meaningful message to say "the page is wrong".  I realise this may be painful but as mentioned I'm still learning - I do really appreciate the help.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Can you execute the code I posted and tell the results?

Comment: thanks for your efforts!  I've updated the original post to show what's happening currently

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Assert on `currentDate.IsDisplayed()` is comparing a bool  (true) against a String